# Better Search box for wordpress

Tags: search, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Please take a look on [this](http://bloggingheat.com/host-images-through-dropbox-to-increase-the-speed-of-your-website.php) WordPress theme, when you click on search icon, a search box appear in the middle of page with a cool effect. I want to add this to my WordPress site. I have looked on google but still no luck,
Please suggest me a plugin or article.

Thanks

Comment: Try bootstrap modal functionality to get functionality same like it.

Comment: To get search like that link you need to add css and jQuery.

Comment: This is actually WordPress. But I just need something to start. Any article?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi There it work like this using bootstrap modal popup.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Search
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Search</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <?php  get_search_form(); ?>
        
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>     
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```