# Regarding WordPress functioning

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Can anyone tell how to add anything like a search bar  in WordPress navbar. I'm currently using WordPress 2017 theme.. if I add something the whole navbar just disappears.

Answer (score 0):

You can use these lines of code in your functions.php

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items','add_search_box', 10, 2 );
function add_search_box( $items, $args ) {
$items .= '<li>' . get_search_form( false ) . 
'</li>';
return $items;
}
```

Comment: I checked with the same theme and it was working fine. Let me know if you have placed it in the right file.

Comment: Try this link (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30430325/better-search-box-for-wordpress) and use the styles used in that website that you mentioned